# Saving image file in external storage works buts images doesnt show up in Gallery immediately

Tags: android

I have having a problem with image saving in android.When i press the save button,then image (.jpg) gets actually saved in the external storage.But the prob is that it does not show in my GALLERY immediately.It shows mayb after few hours ,days o so o never...
For saving following I am using following code:

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item3) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        myDir = new File(root + "/PaintImage");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getAbsolutePath(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Folder gets created in SD card but Gallery does not show up immediately when the image is saved.

THanks for d help in advance.

Comment: have you used media scanner for update gallery

Comment: no i have used media scanner

Comment: you should use Media Scanner as Cristi has suggested go through that link and read documentation

Answer (score 1):

you have to call the Media scanner to update your library

[Media Scanner Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html)